# If one keep one if higher give 2 in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

What wrong with `=IF(AZ>1,"2","1")` a set of numbers in col AZ are 1 or higher and if 1 I want to keep it 1 if higher I want it to be 2.

```
 =IF(AZ>1,"2","1")
```

Comment: You can just use `=IF(AZ>1,2,1)`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. You are a gentleman and a schooler

Comment: A/The likely reason it wasn't working, is when you put the numbers in quote, Excel reads them as a `String`. Removing the quotes treats them as Numbers.

Comment: Yeah... Access habits got me all mixed up. That's my excuse and i am sticking to it.

Comment: `=MIN(AZ,2)` might work depending on what values are possible in AZ

Answer (score 0):

you need to define row too like:

```
=IF(AZ1 > 1, 2, 1)
```